# What is a good way to move an iOS app between business units?

Tags: mobile, ios, appcenter

Our organisation mistakingly created the production app in the wrong business unit App Center. When we tried to re-create it in the correct one, Salesforce complains about the app id `xxx.yyy.com` being already registered.

What is a good way to "move" an iOS app between business units? Any method that doesn't require deleting the old app would work, i.e. changing the old app ID.

Answer (score 0):

We could not find a way to do it and had to start from scratch with a new app.